# Are there special gun prefixes beyond Trick Shot?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I found a Trick Shot Maggie, whose bullets ricochet like a Viral Marketer, but since my Gunstock Maggie didn't have such ricochets, I'm assuming it's due to the Trick Shot prefix.

But it's not in the gun's info card.

And the Borderlands Wiki says nothing about the Trick Shot prefix, so I guess it's a currently undocumented feature?

Are there any other known special effect prefixes? Given the Wiki's [other documented Trick Shot guns](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Special:Search?query=Trickshot&scope=internal&navigationSearch=true), it seems at least Trick Shot isn't limited to Legendary weapons?

Comment: Are you sure this wasn't due to the Jakobs weapon ability where critical hits ricochet?

Comment: @SaintWacko - I fired at the scenery. There was nothing to crit on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below link that specifies "The fire rate accessory has no practical effect on Jakobs pistols; the "Trick Shot" prefix instead causes bullets to ricochet upon hitting walls" - The fire rate accessory is named "Trick shot" on Jakob's weapons.

https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Weapons_by_prefix_(Borderlands_2_%26_Pre-Sequel)

The link provided above also gives the names of the other prefixes of weapons and their effects.

Comment: So, I assume that means the ricochets can't hit anything? Thanks!

Comment: I think they can still enemies but with reduced damage. I can recall this being the case when I've played BL 2 & BL PS previously.